# how to edit like passing through a foggy glass

Tags: photo-editing

I wonder do you have any hint how to edit like the following style with photoshop?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's my terrible rendition of trying to re-create the effect in Photoshop:

[image]

[image]

What I tried was creating a layer mask as an artificial depth map (make the hands closer and the other stuff further away), then used lens blur with the alpha mask to blur the stuff further away more. Then, I adjusted the levels to make it look super gloomy, then added a grey overlay and some noise.

Comment: Great answer! On a technical note, considering the model's nose and chin are closer to the glass than the back of the head, they should probably have more definition in the output image than the back of the head does. But really, great demonstration of what I presume is a quick-and-dirty attempt. =)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not terribly convinced that this is very much post processing at all. Some of these were shot by [Marek Chaloupka “through milk glass.”](https://www.thisiscolossal.com/2013/03/ghostly-hands-and-feet-photographed-through-milk-glass-by-marek-chaloupka/)

I don’t know what “milk glass” is but it appears to be a type of frosted or etched glass or some type of plastic that appears frosted. A large amount of soft light is coming from the subject side of the glass/plastic causing the backlighting and, where the subject touches the glass/plastic, no light can bounce so it appears black.

Standard tweaks may have been done (turn to b&w, contrast, etc) but I believe all these images to have been shot this way on purpose - not a random image edited to look like this.

So, to answer your question: you must first start with an image made from backlighting and shot through “milk glass” and then tweak.

Comment: The milk glass explanation is probably not sufficient for the Miriam Sweeney (horse) and Christopher Wilson (crow) images. Particularly for the Sweeney image, post processing of an image that has nothing to do with milk glass when shot is a far more likely explanation.

Comment: In addition to Michael C's comment, I don't think that this frosted glass is actually anything like [milk glass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_glass) in the traditional sense. I can't quite tell if it's a translation problem or if is just an idea introduced by the reposter blog you link to.

Comment: Miriam Sweeney's horse is not photographic art, as far as I can tell. It's a photograph of an artistic creation of frosted or milk glass with parts of a horse protruding through. She has done other similar pieces with horses and other subjects coming out of or going into a plane (glass, the arthouse wall, etc.).